# Read and Edit TGZ or Zip (containing CSV file) file in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-boot, csv, zip, spring-batch

I have a tgz file which contains the mulitple folder of specific date and each folder contains various CSV files. So I have to edit some of the files in each folder using spring batch, after editing I should have new edited tgz file. I guess I would need to write my own ItemReader and ItemWriter to work with tgz or zip file.

I am not sure how would the implementation will look like, do I'd need to extract them first in ItemReader and then edit them , or only extract the files that I have edit and then write them in tgz file(I am not sure if that's possible). Extracting the whole tgz file will not work because, we don't have enough space, that's why we want to work with tgz or zip file.

And can I directly read from tgz or zip file without extracting them ? Any suggestion how should I build this application ?

Comment: Do these links help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984393/spring-batch-process-an-encoded-zipped-file and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1841

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I don't understand how's that going to help because I have to write again into same zip file and link inside github is dead.

Comment: The links I shared show how to read data from a gzip file without extracting it. For the writing part, I don't think this is even possible (not related to Java at all). If that's the case, I would be curious to see how (even in a non Java world). So if you don't have enough space on the machine running your job, you would try to find a way to use an external temporary storage to implement your requirement.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Hi, I switched to normal java application, it is possible to write in inside zip file without extracting it using ZipFileSystem, there were other file system providers also like for tgz, but didn't explore them. Thanks for the reply

Comment: `it is possible to write in inside zip file without extracting it `: as mentioned in my previous comment, I don't think this is possible at all. If that's the case, I would be curious to see how (even in a non Java world). If you manage to code this outside Spring Batch, you can put that code in an `ItemWriter` and use in in a Spring Batch step.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Yeah, I guess that will work, will try